# How to remove the first sheets or read the second sheets of the excel files

Tags: r, excel, worksheet

I have very unusual and incomprehensible predicament with deleting the first sheets and reading the second sheets of the excel files that I have.

I thought I knew perfectly how to read the second sheet of an excel file:
`read.xlsx2("excelfile.xlsx", SheetIndex = 2)` or `read.xlsx2("excelfile.xlsx", SheetName = "secondsheetsname")`

But everytime I do this, this keeps showing up and its been pain in my arse since I have many of these excel files and need to read their second sheets.

[image: I tried both read.xlsx and read.xlsx2. Since there is nothing in the first sheet, "NULL" shows up when reading it]

I need to read the second sheets of many excel files. Could anyone help me to read the second sheet or enlighten me with deleting the first sheets of the excel files at once or automatically by using R ?

Ive attached [some of the files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rxt78in3yr0m434/AADnaujFKU_mnixyCMs7IlqEa?dl=0) in order to let everyone to try.

Comment: If possible please paste code as text instead of attaching an image. Also please state the libraries you used, I assume you used the `xlsx` library, but there are many libraries to read xlsx files.

Comment: @Japp it was "xlsx" and codes that I used were
read.xlsx2("excelfile.xlsx", SheetIndex = 2)
read.xlsx2("excelfile.xlsx", SheetName = "Partner")
read.xlsx("excelfile.xlsx", 2)

Answer (score 0):

After having tested several solutions to import Excel files into R, I can recommend the `readxl` package:

`require(readxl)`
`read_excel('excelfile.xlsx', sheet = 2)`

Comment: It's not working in my laptop surface pro 3. The first code that I used was 
'read_excel('kor import 2000.xlsx', sheet = 2)'  and it says 
"Error in read_xlsx_(path, sheet, col_names = col_names, col_types = col_types,  : 
  Invalid cell: lacks ref attribute". 
So I tried this code 
'read_excel("kor import 2000.xlsx", sheet = 2, col_names =  TRUE, col_types = NULL, na = "", skip = 0)' and again it shows 
"Error in read_xlsx_(path, sheet, col_names = col_names, col_types = col_types,  : 
  Invalid cell: lacks ref attribute". 
May be its my laptop that has problem.

Comment: More likely an issue with the file. You can try to save the file with another and extension (.xls). Also, just copy and paste the data to a newly created excel file and try to import it with the same method.

Comment: Mine is "freshly" created by JMP.